# jwt-auth after upgrade - get user from request token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I upgraded:

"tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*",

from a very old version, and it seems like the API has changed. I managed to fix the login, using:

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {

        $credentials = $request->only(['username', 'password']);

        $validator = Validator::make($credentials, [
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()) {
            throw new ValidationHttpException($validator->errors()->all());
        }


        if (!$token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        $user = auth()->user();
        $user->ip_address = $request->ip();
        if ($request->device_token)
        $user->device_token = $request->device_token;
        $user->save();

        $data['token'] = $token;
        $data['email'] = $user->email;

        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

So my login work, but all API's that required the token - fail now.

Example of API that fail:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
        {
            // $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
        }


        public function enterWorld(Request $request)
        {

            $token = $request->input('token');
            $user = JWTAuth::toUser($token);
            return $user;

        }
```

Any idea how to convert the token from the request to the user with the new API?
 I couldn't find any docs about it.

I tried:

return response()->json(auth()->user());

but in this API it return empty array. only in login it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$user = JWTAuth::setRequest($request)->user();
```

You may also explicitly set the guard when using the following syntax:

```
// pass the guard in to the auth() helper.
return response()->json(auth('jwt')->user());
```

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that the token returned from my login example is `true`, so this method return nothing. Any idea ?

Comment: Have you added the `Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject` interface to your user model?

Comment: Yes, I added this interface

Comment: I'll accept the answer and open new one regards this